# Regularity properties of Turing-invariant and arbitrary sets of reals

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

The question whether Turing determinacy implies $AD$ is a well-known open problem. I was wondering if anything is known about the following analogous question:

Let $\Gamma$ be a regularity property (e.g. Lebesgue measurability, Baire property, $\mathbb P$-measurability for a reasonable arboreal forcing $\mathbb P$, etc). Assuming $ZF+DC+"\Gamma$ holds for all Turing-invariant sets of reals$"$, does it follow that $\Gamma$ holds for all sets of reals?

Comment: I'm expecting not a whole lot more is known than can be deduced from Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00525), but I'm hoping for better answers in some cases.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais The paper looks interesting, but its relevance to the question is not immediately clear to me. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: What about $\Gamma$ being all Turing-invariant sets?

Comment: Have you thought about degrees generated by a locally countable Borel quasi-partial order?

Comment: @喻良 Not yet. Is there a candidate for such a quasi-partial order that might make the problem more easy to approach?

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you mean?

Comment: Isn't being Turing invariant a regularity property? I don't know, it was meant half as a joke. Well, mostly as a joke.

Answer (score 2):

Here is not an answer but an example:

Let **PSP** be the statement that every uncountable set of reals has a perfect subset and **TPSP** that every uncountable set of Turing degrees has a perfect subset.

Then **PSP** and **TPSP** are equivalently consistent over $ZF+DC$.

Clearly over $ZF+DC$, **PSP** implies **TPSP** but I don't know whether the inverse is true.

Comment: Indeed, once you consider the consistency strength version of the question, it is my conjecture that the answer should be affirmative (in the case of Lebesgue measurability, I worked with Shelah to show that $\Sigma^1_3$-Lebesgue measurability is equiconsistent with the Turing invariant version of the statement, though we never finished writing the paper as it turned out to be too similar to the original "Solovay's inaccessible"). However, for the original question, a counterexample won't be too extremely surprising.